# Order of "sometimes" relative to the subject of a sentence in the passive voice

Tags: grammar, british-english, speech, descriptive-grammar, style-manuals

I have a doubt that is the following one:

I have two alternative sentence transformations of this sentence below and, I wonder if it is possible to write the adverb "sometimes" before the subject "the shopping" in the first sentence and, if its grammatically correct as a sentence that is transformed. On the other way round, I also would like to know if the second sentence is correct. Many thanks!

> He sometimes does the shopping. (active voice)

Sentence transformed::

- The shopping sometimes is done by him. (first option)
- Sometimes, the shopping is done (by him). (second option)

Comment: You would normally say "THE SHOPPING *IS SOMETIMES* DONE BY HIM" rather than "THE SHOPPING *SOMETIMES IS* DONE BY HIM."  You also wouldn't normally shout it.  Why all the caps?

Comment: The caps are to distinguish the sentences so that people who are reading me knows it :-)

Comment: I, personally, am able to tell the difference between sentences even when they are normally capitalized, I suspect that most people are.

Comment: Well, some people are not able to see it that is why i wrote it this way. I hope you can understand. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I do not understand why the adverb cannot be placed after the subject. I do not see it bad at all.

Comment: I'm not saying it's bad, I'm telling you how people would ***normally*** say it.

Comment: Ok. Are you an expert in Grammar?

Comment: My University professor said your answer as well but, I disagree with it because i think that placing the adverb after the subject is not bad at all and it sounds well.

Comment: I have seen some grammar books and some of them say that we can place the adverb after the subject. I think it depends on the person and sentence transformations are not objective at all because you can make a hundred sentence transformation in 100 different ways in the English Language. Its going to depend on the perspective of the other person. But, I would like that anybody else let me know what does he or she think thinks about what do I think about this structure because I was thinking approximately during a week. No joke

Comment: As I have said, or at least implied, a few times now, I'm not telling you what is grammatically right or wrong, I am telling you the **convention**.  I am assuming that your ultimate aim is to communicate more effectively in the English language, and doing this requires a knowledge of conventions as well as grammar.

Comment: In fact, I need a person that is a pro in Grammar and a lingüist to answer me this question because I doubt of what my professor said and i disagree with it. Thanks for your arguments, Ill take them into consideration as well. Let me read what you wrote.

Comment: Hi Sara! Welcome to UL&U. I've formatted your question for you. If you don't like the reformatting you can click on the edit box under your post and then roll it back. :-)

Comment: ' I do not see it bad at all.' indicates that ELL is quite possibly a better place to post questions for some time. // Placement of adverbs has been covered here before, though, as Max implies, it is a complex and often unpredictable art rather than an exact science. // Here, with the pronoun 'him', the passive construction would probably be considered unusual anyway, except for differential emphasis.

Comment: Im new here. Ill post it next time in another post .

Answer (score 1):

If you say "The shopping *is sometimes* done by him", it's a simple statement of fact.  Let's say that there's a "him" and a "her" in this situation.  Sometimes he does it, sometimes she does it.  Simple.

However, if you say "The shopping sometimes is done by him" it moves the focus onto the word "is", which in turn implies that it has previously been suggested that he **does not sometimes do the shopping**, ie that he never does the shopping, and that this sentence is **refuting** that other implied statement.  Eg

"He never does the shopping."
"No, the shopping sometimes *is* done by him."

Although, in this example, people would tend to say

"No, he sometimes *does* do the shopping."

Comment: I said: "The shopping sometimes is done by him"

Comment: Placing the adverb at the beginning, at the middle and, at the end makes sense.

Comment: Sometimes, the shopping is done by him

Comment: The shopping sometimes is done by him

Comment: The shopping is done by him sometimes.

Comment: Here, they also place sometimes after the subject http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/sometimes

Comment: @ Sara I think the usual way is to put the adverb of frequency after the verb (be). Or you can use it initially as your last example

Comment: First sentence - "is sometimes is" - accidental second 'is'?